# How to elegantly remove values in a column based on 5 day/idx rule?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as given below

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
     'flag' : ['','','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','','','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1','T1']
 })
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

As per the rule/logic, `T1` can appear in flag field only after `5` days/records from it's first occurrence. For example if `T1` had occurred on `3rd` index, it can then only occur on `9th` index and more..Anything before that are invalid and has to be removed.

I tried the below. Though this works, it doesn't look elegant and not suitable for all subjects.

```
a = test1[test1['flag']=='T1'].index.min()
test1.loc[a+1:a+6, 'flag'] = ''
```

How can I do this check indvidually for all the subjects? Each subject and its flag should follow this rule

I expect my output to be like as shown below. You can see the invalid flags are removed

[image]

Comment: Both the answers below are good. However I can mark only one answer as solution.So I fo with @WeNYoBen as it was short. Nonetheless, Both the answers provide expected output and it is upvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
s=test1['flag'].eq('T1').groupby(test1['subject_id']).transform('idxmax')
test1.loc[~((test1.index==s)|(test1.index>(s+5))),'flag']=''
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different way to do it, in a single piped statement. For clarity, I'm creating additional columns for the cumsum and the condition and then sub-setting the dataframe.

```
test1.\
    assign(cum_sum=lambda x: x.flag.eq('T1').groupby(x.subject_id).cumsum()).\
    assign(condition=lambda x: (x.flag=='') | (x.cum_sum==1) | (x.cum_sum >=5)).\
    loc[lambda x: x.condition]
```

Hope this helps.